# Powershell, remove specific characters (spaces and hyphens)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've got this string :  `'  - app-name'`. So that's double spaces, hyphen, space, name of the app.

I want to get rid of these double spaces, hyphen, space. So the result would be `app-name`

I tried `'  - app-name'.Trim("  - ", " ")` but that doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Replace() method on the string:

```
$test = "  - app-name"
$test.replace(" - ", "")
```

Output: `appname`

Comment: Thanks it worked, the exact solution is `.replace("  - ", "")`, if you want to edit your answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

`Trim` accepts only one argument.

`'  - app-name'.Trim("  - ")` works.